# eight queens in c using recursion

Tags: c, n-queens

I'm trying to solve the eight queens problem using recursion, and I am just lost.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: Indentation of code doesn't matter for the compiler, but it's very important for us to better see and understand what the code is doing. So please edit your question to improve the indentation.

Comment: Your code naver makes it to the line with `print_matrix();`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several errors:

- In your code, `id` is the number of the queen you want tom place on the board. If you increment that by `N` in each step and start at `id == 0`, you can never reach `id == N*N - 1`. Increment by one and test for `id == N - 1`.
- When you recurse, you set the the square where you put the queen to 1, but when you return from the recursion, you don't set it back. That means that you gradually fill your board, so that there are no valid moves. You should set the quare to 0 again after the recrsive call, so that subsequent recursions don't see the queens placed by previous ones.
- Because you consider all squares for each queen*, your validity check must be general. It is not enough to consider all rows and columns up to the current one. You must check all 8 rows and all 8 columns. (* Well, you skip the first `id` rows, but you can still place queen 4 in row 7 and the next queen in row 5.)
- When you place queens, you consider all squares from the current row on. That's not only wasteful, it will also print duplicates of some solutions. Consider my example above: A solution with queen 4 in row 7 and queen 5 in row 5 will be the same as the solution with queen 4 in row 5 and queen 5 in row 7. Your program would print both. Therefore, place the queen number `id` in row number `id`. (That means that you can skip the test for queens in the same row in `valid`, but you should still test all columns.)

Answer (score 0):

Think about:

```
void playQueen(int queen){
  if testOk(queen) playQueen(queen+1));
}

void main(){
  playQueen(1);
}
```